# How to set v-model if the elements are dynamic?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have a component A which acts wrapper for lot of components using slot and slot property, it looks like this

```
<component-A :some-prop="foo">
     <component-B slot-scope="slotProps"></component-B>
</component-A>
```

all the dynamic components wrapped in a component-A get data from a single object, it has all the keys and values.The component A does this funcionality, it takes in a component clone it to right side and change all input fields(text, selection boxes) on left side to  tag (except radios, checkboxes), i did the cloning with custom js,the radios  and checkboxes needed to be set v-model after i replace the element type in dom tree, is it possible? is there any way to set v-model programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you have original data fetched by **component A**, then **component A** clone some data and inject them in fields on left side, then for sure your fields data on left side (cloned ones) are bound to a different X model. To update the v-model programatically, is to **update the X model** as below:

**Component:**

```
<div >
  <li v-for="color in colors">
    <checkbox :checked="color.checked" > {{color.name}}
    </li>
  </li>
</div>
...
data: { return {
                  colors: [{name: 'red', checked: true},
                           {name: 'blue', checked: true},
                           {name: 'black', checked: false}]
               }
       }
....
methods: {
check_all_colors(){
  // example to update model that reflects on checkbox fields
  colors.forEach(function(element){
    element.checked = true
  });
 }
}
```